# How can I install pg_hint_plan on amazon RDS Postgres 13

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pg-hint-plan

I am trying to install [pg_hint_plan](https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_hint_plan) in order to manipulate my query plans. on my amazon RDS with postgres 13.

I successfully added the extension with `CREATE EXTENSION pg_hint_plan` which makes the extension appear in the list of installed exceptions `select * from pg_catalog.pg_extension`

However when I try to use hints on my queries, nothing happens.
For example when i try to force an error as displayed on the documentation:

[image]

I get no error from the pg_hint_plan on my output, and its like the hint is ignored
[image]

Is there any mistake on the configuration? From what I understood I dont need to do LOAD 'pg_hint_plan' as specified on the documentation because I am using Amazon RDS

Answer (score 2):

Before this will work you need to alter the database parameters for shared_preload_libraries to contain pg_hint_plan. Then'll you'll need to bounce the cluster. After that it should work.

Comment: Seems to come preloaded in Aurora but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @PreslavLe Did you run "CREATE EXTENSION pg_hint_plan"? If so, did the output of  "select * from pg_catalog.pg_extension" reveal anything useful?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. CREATE EXTENSION pg_hint_plan worked, select * from pg_catalog.pg_extension reveals nothing useful. No type hints are honored, no errors. Is there a way to confirm if the extension is loaded and getting triggered?

Comment: Any solution so far?

Comment: Parameter group needs to be modified after `create extension ...` (probably it can be done before as well) .  From RDS console , select cluster , go to "Configuration",   open link under "DB cluster parameter group" . Then search for "shared_preload_libraries" parameter and append pg_hint_plan. The value would look, for instance, `pg_stat_statements,pg_hint_plan`. Save parameters.  After, you'll need to restart instances.   Note, if you're using default parameter group, you will first have to create a custom parameter group, then modify cluster to use your parameter group instead of default.